# C#. Создать массив из 10 чисел. Вычислить сумму нечетных элементов массива

Tags: c#

Я пытался сделать это вручную указывая все 10 переменных в массиве. Теперь я не знаю как вывести сумму нечетных элементов. Помогите пожалуйста.

Код :

```cs
int[] A = new int[10];
int a = A[0];
int b = A[1];
int c = A[2];
int d = A[3];
int e = A[4];
int f = A[5];
int g = A[6];
int h = A[7];
int i = A[8];
int j= A [9];
float s = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Введите а");
a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите b");
b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите c");
c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите d");
d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите e");
e = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите f");
f = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите g");
g = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите h");
h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите i");
i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите j");
j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Вам нужно прочитать главу про массивы и про циклы, код сократится сразу многократно.

Comment: А где можно такую информацию узнать ?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.4.php

Comment: А можно как-либо присвоить значению nums переменную ? Код : int[] nums = new int[10];
            nums[0] = Console.ReadLine(a);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массивы и циклы, циклы и массивы. Если на начальных этапах обучения у вас массив есть, а цикла нет, значит что-то пошло не так.

```cs
int[] a = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Введите a[{i}] = ");
    a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] % 2 == 1)
        sum += a[i];
}
Console.WriteLine($"Сумма нечетных чисел = {sum}");
```

А еще есть Linq  вариант

```
int[] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i =>
    {
        Console.Write($"Введите a[{i}] = ");
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }).ToArray();
int sum = a.Where(x => x % 2 == 1).Sum();
Console.WriteLine($"Сумма нечетных чисел = {sum}");
```

Comment: А как еще найти наибольшее отриц число ?

Comment: @Kekkx вам точно не интереснее решить задачу самостоятельно?

Comment: Я пишу код для игры(фан мейд игры), застрял на создание массивов для оружия.

Comment: @Kekkx а, ну если для игры, то Linq `int maxNegative = a.Where(x => x < 0).Max();` подойдет. Я думал, что для преподавателя. `using System.Linq;` только в самом начале кода допишите.

Comment: Я использую юнити и это такой гемор. Он вообще не распознает ошибки. По этому мне и требуется помощь иногда.

Comment: Почему бы не тестировать куски кода в Visual Studio или VSCode ? Вам точно нужны массивы? Может проще будет со списками List?

Comment: @Archery А может лучше стек или очередь, а может вообще словарь? К чему это вы? Массив - отличное решение (гораздо эффективнее и мощнее списка), когда количество элементов известно заранее и не будет изменяться. Иначе массивов бы просто не существовало, просто какой смысл в массиве, если список всегда лучше?

Comment: @aepot Просто списки динамические. Во многих отношениях с ними проще работать. Может автор  вопроса вообще не знает об их существовании. Потому и предложила.

Comment: @Archery судя по всему, автору еще многое предстоит узнать, прежде чем он до них доберется с пониманием происходящего. Он, как я понял, пытается пилить игры, а там производительность важна, а массив почти всегда быстрее списка. Вот если бы он пришел с вопросом, "а как менять размер массива", тогда бы я и сам предложил `List<T>`.

Comment: @Kekkx  Если юнити не распознаёт ошибки и нужна помощь - поставьте linqpad, это простенький блокнот в котором можно проверять небольшие фрагменты текста.

Answer (score -1):

Для начала, ты неправильно считываешь массив. Надо Console.Read(A[i]), i-индекс элемента. Для того, чтобы определить, является ли элемент нечётным, надо разделить его на 2 и посмотреть, равен ли его остаток 1. a%2==1

Comment: "Надо Console.Read(A[i])" - нет, не надо.

Comment: Вы бы протестировали сначала код, который предлагаете в ответе.

Comment: А можно как-либо присвоить значению nums переменную ? Код : int[] nums = new int[10]; nums[0] = Console.ReadLine(a);